# Is this a valid way to show multiple divs with delays in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this a valid way to show multiple divs with delays in jquery?
it works fine but i was wondering if there is a better way?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#heading").delay(100).show(500);
      $("#column1").delay(2200).show(500);
        $("#column2").delay(2400).show(500);
          $("#column3").delay(2600).show(550);
            $("#column4").delay(2700).show(500);
              $("#column5").delay(2800).show(500);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/hkccLedu/

Comment: before asking about validity, why would you do this? at all?

Comment: Yes, it's a completely valid way to do that, and if there's no specific interval between the delays, there's no better way to do it really, other than maps and loops etc. which isn't neccessarely better or easier to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little counter intuitive. Put a class on them that is the same so you only have one CSS rule. If I was going to have a page with multiple columns to show, I would use a $.each loop on them. If they are loaded dynamically, the number of columns may vary per page.

http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/ym2Lrwat/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#heading").delay(1100).show(500);
    var count = 1600;
    var interval = 500
    $(".column").each(function () {
        $(this).delay(count).show(500);
        count += interval;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks i thought there would be something like that using var

Comment: can i add a second div to the each list like this>

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#heading").delay(1100).show(500);
    var count = 1600;
    var interval = 200
    $(".column,.column2").each(function () {
        $(this).delay(count).show(500);
        count += interval;
    });
});